# Decimal to Hexadecimal conversion working in Linux but not in Unix

Tags: printf, floating-point, numeric-data

I want to convert a decimal number to hexadecimal number. 
I used the command :

```
printf '%X\n' 053698180
```

This command is working perfectly fine on Linux server. But throwing the below error when tried on UNIX :

```
printf: Error converting 053698180
053698180
```

What could be the issue here?

Also, what is the least possible correction that can be made here so as to make it work on UNIX and Linux both?

Comment: Actually, it is not working perfectly fine.  You are using the Z shell and you have the `octalzeroes` option turned off.  The Bourne Again shell, the Debian Almquist shell, the Korn shell, and the external `printf` command on your Linux system will all print error messages with these arguments, as indeed will the Z shell with the `octalzeroes` option turned on.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't tell us what is your Unix and your shell. The problem lies probably in the leading `0` which instructs `printf` to interpret the number as an octal number, which it can't be (due to the 8 and 9 digits).

Just remove the leading `0`.